# Laravel 5.1 Session::flash stopped working

Tags: session, laravel-5.1, flash-message

While developing my webapp I found that my flash messages stopped working and I can't find what is causing this.

In my template I have this markup:

```
@if (Session::has('alert'))
            <div class="flash-message">
                @foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
                    @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
                        <div class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }}</div>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <!-- end .flash-message -->
 @endif
```

And in the controllers I use Session::flash like this:

```
Session::flash('alert-warning', trans('messages.succesful_verified'));
```

What can cause this? The messages stopped working suddenly without modify nothing.

I also have in the template a markup to show errors and it is working perfectly but flash messages don't.

Comment: I see you're checking for `Session::has('alert')` in your view but storing `alert-warning` as your key in `Session::flash('alert-warning',....)`.  Is that first `@if` returning true?

Comment: @dtj it's clearly that the problem, the condition is returning false but I don't understand why this condition stops working suddenly because it was working fine before it started failing.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what to tell you. It's impossible for that query to ever be true given the discrepancy in key names.